# Is php output buffering necessary here?

Tags: php, output, buffering

I hope you can help this newbie. Working on understanding the php output buffering and I came across this php code in some file I'm working on:

```
        ...
        ...
        ob_end_clean();


        ob_start();

        display_user_list();

        $value = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $this->display_field_content($value);
```

I am trying to understand if this is similar to:

```
        $this->display_field_content(display_user_list(););
```

So does it really make sense to use output buffering in this case?

Thank you in advance!
Ozgur

Comment: If the function `display_user_list()` echos output, then yes, output buffering would be necessary. If the function returns content then you should store the result as a variable `$list = display_user_list();` so it's being not output but can be used further down your script and then output buffering is not necessary. Seeing that this code came from a class, you should probably store the result as a variable.